# How to disable key-touch search in windows explorer in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

It used to be that when you are in windows file explorer and press a key or a type a key sequence it would highlight the first match, then if you repeat the second match and so on... Now this behavior changed and whenever I type anything a file search is initiated. Can I disable this search switch back to the old behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following setting in your Folder Options:

[image: Search Settings]

It should be `Select the typed item in the view`.